# Laravel como redireccionar a usuario a home una vez haya expirado su sesión?

Tags: laravel, auth

Tengo 3 guards de usuarios diferentes con sus respectivos logins y logouts, el problema esque cuando expira la sesión en lugar de ser dirigidos al Home, el sistema muestra que intenta acceder a un objeto que no existe porque ya no está la sesión activa.

No estoy usando Middleware, ya que el frontend lo tengo en el mismo Laravel, osea blade.php

Así se ve mi Logout para el usuario admin, es lo mismo para el usuario tipo vendedor y web

```
 public function logout(){
        auth()->guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Sé que en App/Middleware/Authenticate.php existe un método el cual redirige a otra página en caso de que no esté autenticado, pero no tengo idea de como usarlo.

Gracias!

Comment: Es un login desde cero o usas algún paquete?

Comment: hice un php artisan make:auth